# Fastlane match passphrase forgotten

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

I am working an iOS project that’s being deployed with Fastlane.
However, during the Fastlane match, I don’t have the password to decrypt the repo.

Here is the error message :

> bad decrypt - Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!

How could I reset it ..?
Looking at community's questions, I tried several manipulations, like Fastlane nuke, but the current password is asked.

Here is my MatchFile :

```
git_url "https://xxx/_git/xxx"
git_branch "master"
clone_branch_directly true
force_for_new_devices true

type "development"

username "xxx@xxx.com"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you still need the encrypted credentials or can you just replace them? `nuke` is for cleaning up your account and start new with a new (or cleaned) Git repository.

Comment: No I don’t absolutly need these credentials. I need to bypass or reset this passphrase un ordre to be able to publish my app. Do I need to create a new repo ? Is there another solution ?

Comment: how did you fixed this problem? @ClémentFvr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new commit to the repo that deletes all the files and folder, then you are also rid of the passphrase. It is only used to encrypt the actual file in the repository.

Then you can create new credentials by using `match nuke`, and then `match` again.

Note: If you are using Enterprise profiles, you don't want to do this as it will break the apps that are currently installed on your user's devices.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it still doesn't ask for a new passphrase after I delete all of the files and run nuke.